# OAuth + spring security for internal REST communication

Tags: java, rest, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0

### Setup

We're developing a distributed application with **Java and Spring** where our existing client front end (complete with its own authentication, database, accounts, etc.) uses **REST** calls to access our new server for additional services. We want to protect these resources with **Oauth**.

Access should be restricted by **role or account**. However we don't want the user on the client side to have to worry about any additional authentication apart from the already **existing account**. At the same time we need to provide a means for third party applications to access some resources from the outside after going through some kind of registration against the server (which is why we're distributing in the first place).

So we have set up **spring security** on the server side to provide accounts that should be used to **restrict access to the resources**. The **user should log in on the client side** and then be able to access only those **server resources** assigned to him. We have some kind of registration process that sets up the user on the client side to be able to access the server services so any account setup I think should be done there.

### So the questions are

How can I enable the client side to obtain an access token for the protected resources without the user having to log in to his server-side account?

And how do I setup the server side account without needing any user input?

### My thoughts

**This won't do**

I'm thinking I'll have to either tell the client about a new account created on the server side for that user (but then, how would I choose and communicate a password?) or synchronize the client side account to the server, and use those credentials to authenticate the client against the server and generate access tokens. But how save can that be? Also the server has a much higher security (one way encrypted, salted passwords) on its accounts and I don't really want to compromise this by using the less save client accounts.

**Maybe this will?**

Maybe the way to go will be to tell the server about the client account during the first authentication, create an account on the server side, store the generated token on the client side and then authenticate the client against the server with that token for each subsequent request..? Will the server be able to log-in the client using its server-side account via that token for each request?
I'd need a special resource for that initial (2-legged?) handshake that can only be accessed from the client server, right?

Also:
Which would be better suited for the task, OAuth 1 or 2?

I'm hoping someone understands my problem and can help me sort through possible missunderstandings and knowledge gaps (I'm reading through Oauth and spring security documentations right now, so I'll update if I come up with a clearer picture and thus clearer questions of what to do)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So our current status is to use **OAuth2** mostly for reasons of simplicity. We're also sure that the flaws it might have concerning security we can cover ourselves as needed and they will most likely be addressed in the future by the implementation vendors or the IETF.

To handle the communication between REST server and REST client (both in our control) we use the formerly known as 2-legged authentication, now client credentials grant. I've asked a few questions on SO about that including

- our current [spring-security context setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138556/spring-security-context-setup-for-2-legged-client-credentials-oauth2-server)
- the [client credentials flow in particular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140020/understanding-oauth2-client-credentials-flow)
- the use of [long lived tokens versus reauthentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14315777/oauth2-long-lived-tokens-vs-reauthentication-in-a-client-credentials-flow)
- and how to [limit REST access by HTTP method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316506/oauth2-with-spring-security-limit-rest-access-by-http-method)

---

Concerning the use of client based user accounts for authentication against the server we didn't get any further.

For now we authenticate the user against our old client web application as before and then authenticate the client against the server 2-legged. In theory this will allow  any user to access any resource using the client accesstoken but for now that's okay for us so we will not investigate further down that road.

Still, should anyone have a good idea on how this might be solved we'll pick it up, just to tighten security further. So, I'll leave this question open.

My thoughts currently are along the line of registering a new client ID for each user on the authentication server with a generated secret and then synchronize those back to the client server and use those client_id / secret combinations to access resources for a user represented by the generated client_id in a client credentials flow.

For our latest application we'll store accounts on the REST server (authentication provider) and have the user login against that server and then use the token to access the REST resources as intended by the spec.

Comment: Two years further, and I'll report you that I haven't found a better approach (or rather, a more secure approach) up to date. I intend to use oauth 2.0 password grant, not client credentials. There is no client secret, only a clientid which we pass. The vulnerability is that if anyone gets a hold of our refresh_token, they can basically get unlimited access if they keep using the token to request new tokens. That's unfortunately the drawback we have, but I haven't found a way to prevent it.