# Oauth2 - long lived Tokens vs Reauthentication in a Client Credentials Flow

Tags: security, rest, oauth-2.0, access-token, 2-legged

We've secured our REST server with **OAuth2** and implemented the **client credentials** grant type for several client apps that we control. Now we're faced with the decision to either make the tokens **long lived** (i.e. they expire "never") or to have the clients **reAuthenticate** very often (depending on the refresh token expiration). The first means that a captured token could be used by a malicious party the second means exposing the client secret very often which then in turn can be used to obtain tokens.

Which is more secure in a resource-server to client-server authentication? 
Both token and client secret can be invalidated if we suspect a theft. Obviously all communication is done via **https**..

Currently we're thinking the client secret is more powerful than the token and thus a long lived token should be better for this two-legged scenario. (For any three-legged grant type which we'll implement soon we'd prefer a short lived token acting as the user session).

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [the specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-4.4), the **client credentials flow** is only allowed for clients that are not running the risk of having its **client secret** stolen:

> The client credentials grant type MUST only be used by confidential clients.

So, if you are using this flow in conjunction with an application on an untrusted platform, you should definitely reconsider this decision.

With the prerequisite that your platform is trusted, there is no need to worry about a stolen **client secret**. Your decision then comes down weighing up the time an attacker can play with a stolen **access token** versus the additional overhead for the **reauthentication** (only [one call](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-4.4), but nonetheless a small delay). The **reauthentication step** itself is a non-issue concerning the exposure of your client secrect, when both participants are trusted and you're using a good transport layer security against MITM attacks.

Also note, that it is [not recommended](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31#section-4.4.3) (and also unnecessary) to use **refresh tokens** with the **client credentials flow**:

> A refresh token SHOULD NOT be included.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We'll probably go with the long lived token, adding a Persistence layer so we can invalidate the token from time to time. But there are two more questions that your answer raised. For readability I'll add them to my post. I'd appreciate your thoughts on those.