# OAuth2 with spring-security - limit REST access by HTTP method

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, scope, oauth-2.0

So we've implemented the **OAuth2 - client credentials grant** between our **REST server** and a **client application server** using **spring-security** . The client can access its resources with the token it gets using client credentials authentication.

What I don't get are the **Scopes** I can set up for a client and the resources.

I explicitly said, **Client A** has **Role X** with **Scope READ** and I said **Resource U** can be accessed with **Role X** and **Scope READ**. Now I expect the resource to reject any `DELETE` or `POST` request but apparently I am mistaken. If I send a `HTTP DELETE` to **Resource U** it will get through.

So it looks like the Scopes are meaningless in my setup. How can I make use of them?

Or do I still need to limit access at the resource itself as I suggested below?

---

Snippets from our setup:

```
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <oauth:client client-id="the_client"
        authorized-grant-types="client_credentials" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT"
        scope="read" secret="secret" />
</oauth:client-details-service>


<http pattern="/rest/**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/persons" access="ROLE_CLIENT,SCOPE_READ" />

    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
```

The REST resource:

```
@Path("/persons")
@Named
public class PersonRest {

    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getAll(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        // ...
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Transactional
    public Response delete(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        // ...
    }
```

---

**Is there any "simple" configuration to tell spring security on the server side, that ROLE_READ should allow only GET requests?**

Or do I need some `@PreAuthorize` annotation or context setup for the specific resource?

So, would something like that work: ?

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasScope(read)")
    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    // ...
    public Response delete(@PathParam("id") String id) {
```

Though that would be horrible news if I had to do it this way as then I'd have to configure each resource individually...

Maybe I can make use of some **filter**?

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you use

```
@RolesAllowed({"customRole"})
```

to protect your HTTP Method , and convert Oauth scope to {customRole} using a Filter

or have you tried

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/persons" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER_READ')" method="GET"/>
```

or something similar

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But like I said I'd rather not have to annotate all my REST methods individually but rather have the permissions setup in one place. Also I don't want to convert a scope to a role. I could just use a role in the first place for that and no scopes at all.

Comment: have you tried `<security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/persons" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER_READ')" method="READ"/>` or something similar

Comment: Ah, I think that's what I was looking for! `<intercept-url pattern="/rest/persons" access="ROLE_PERSONS,SCOPE_READ" method="GET"/>` And then I define another role for the post and delete calls.. I'll give it a try. Thanks!